# Change url in htaccess didnt work

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have this url

```
   mywebsite/chat.php?room=somenameHere
```

I want to change it like:

```
   mywebsite/chat/somenameHere
```

I have tried that:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews

 ## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/?$ /details.php?object=1&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$ /details.php?object=0&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^chat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ chat.php?room=$1 [NC,L]
```

But nothing happen , it didnt work , is there something wrong ? i have looked many tutorials which all say same as i done.

Thanks for guidance!

EDIT:

im getting same page without changing anything and no error. getting this:

```
  mywebsite/chat.php?room=somenameHere
```

Comment: Are you getting 404 or what?

Comment: @anubhava edited what im getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mainwebsite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /chat\.php\?room=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ chat/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/?$ details.php?object=1&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$ details.php?object=0&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^chat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ chat.php?room=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

**EDIT:** As per comments below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hej:)! sorry to disturbe you again :) , i changed my mind:) , i want change this `mywebsite/chat.php?room=somenameHere` to just this `mywebsite/chat?room=somenameHere` , just remove php extension , and thanks so much.